# How do I change elytra texture based on its custom name?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm working on a name-based texture pack for my SMP, and have figured out a majority of things but elytra and trident. I feel like trident will be easier once I get the elytra, and I've looked up tutorials but none show how. If I can't do this and need to make another elytra image folder with a different name/texture, I would like an explanation on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on java, i would reccomend using the `CustomModelData` NBT tag;
there are lots of tutorials on how to use it.

On the other hand, if you're on Bedrock then I don't know how to help you.

Comment: you also need to specify what the CustomModelData does in a recourse pack, in some json file iirc